# Entity Framework 6 Changes Stored Procedure Entity Return Type

Tags: .net, vb.net, sql-server-2008, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

In Entity Framework 6, I've often experience when you configure a function import to return an entity as it's return type:

```
spSelectEntityByID
  Returns Type Entity
```

It will sometimes change the stored procedure to be like:

```
spSelectEntityByID
  Returns Integer
```

I have no idea why because I didn't change anything, EF has a mind of it's own on this one.  If I allow it to create a complex type:

```
spSelectEntityByID
  Returns spSelectEntityByIDResult (Complex Type)
```

It works fine, it never gets changed.  But only for the entity type it may change when updating the model, to update something else but not that stored procedure.  The query is as simple as:

```
select Field1,
       .
       .
from   dbo.Entities
inner join dbo.RelatedTable1
..
inner join dbo.RelatedTable2
..
where
(
   ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(Field1)), '') = '' and
   ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(Field2)), '') = ''
)
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Is it CodeFirst or DatabaseFirst. How does your StoredProcedure look like?

Comment: Database First.  Not a complex stored procedure at all, just one select statement.

Comment: But what does it return? Can it be it returns different resultsets depending on parameter? Do you have a repro?

Comment: Stored proc updated above